# What's going on with the lambda expression in this python function?

Tags: python, lambda

Why does this attempt at creating a list of curried functions not work?

```
def p(x, num):
    print x, num

def test():
    a = []
    for i in range(10):
        a.append(lambda x: p (i, x))
    return a

>>> myList = test()
>>> test[0]('test')
9 test
>>> test[5]('test')
9 test
>>> test[9]('test')
9 test
```

What's going on here?

A function that actually does what I expect the above function to do is:

```
import functools
def test2():
    a = []
    for i in range (10):
        a.append(functools.partial(p, i))
    return a


>>> a[0]('test')
0 test
>>> a[5]('test')
5 test
>>> a[9]('test')
9 test
```

Comment: Since you have a solution that uses functools.partial, what is the question?

Comment: The question is, why doesn't the first method work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Python, variables created in loops and branches aren't scoped. All of the functions you're creating with `lambda` have a reference to the same `i` variable, which is set to `9` on the last iteration of the loop.

The solution is to create a function which returns a function, thus scoping the iterator variable. This is why the `functools.partial()` approach works. For example:

```
def test():
    def makefunc(i):
        return lambda x: p(i, x)
    a = []
    for i in range(10):
        a.append(makefunc(i))
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can also bind the i to an outer lambda for the lazy.

```
def p(x, num):
    print x, num

def test():
    a = []
    for i in range(10):
        a.append((lambda i :lambda x: p (i, x))(i))
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

I was always confused as to why this doesn't work. Thanks for the explanation, '[a paid nerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102704/a-paid-nerd)'. I personally prefer this solution:

```
for i in range(10):
    a.append(lambda num, val_i=i: p (val_i, num))
```

Note the `val_i=i` default argument of the `lambda` that enables to capture the instantaneous value of `i` during the loop whilst still effectively making `lambda` a function of 1 variable. (BTW: changed your `x` into `num` to match `p`'s definition.) I like it better because:

1. it is very close to the original idea and avoids having to define a new named function, precisely the purpose of a lambda...
2. avoids importing `functools`
3. and avoids imbricating lambdas...

Just did a search and found more detailed explanations for the same problem there: [Scope of python lambda functions and their parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters)

Comment: The named argument is why this works and why your original didn't. Here's my exploration of closures in Python: https://gist.github.com/maxcountryman/5035489

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question, and got two answers. One basically the same as the accepted answer here, and the other which is less clear but slightly more succint.

[Dynamically creating a menu in Tkinter. (lambda expressions?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728356/dynamically-creating-a-menu-in-tkinter-lambda-expressions)

Comment: Which includes (and I finally understand now) the lambda x=x : ... hack.