# Nested Lambdas in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, lambda, nested, closures

I'm a beginning python programmer, and I'd like someone to clarify the following behavior.

I have the following code:

```
env = lambda id: -1

def add(id, val, myenv):
    return lambda x: val if x == id else myenv(id)

test_env = add("a", 1, env)
test_env_2 = add("b", 2, test_env)
```

When I look up "a" in `test_env`, it functions correctly, but when I look it up in `test_env_2` it seems to have been clobbered by "b".  At least, "b" is all I can retrieve from `test_env_2`.

So, I have already read [Scope of python lambda functions and their parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters) et al and understand that closures operate on references rather than values, but I believe this is not the exact same case since I am using string literals.  Can someone explain to me what is going on under the hood here?

(And yes, I know that Python isn't intended as a functional language.  This is just research.)

Comment: Python is multiparadigm, but functional style is considered pythonically!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just confused `myenv(id)` with `myenv(x)`. Change it and you'll get the desired output.