# Get text from QPushButton in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots

I'm trying to create a simple keyboard from list of QtGui.QPushButton objects.

```
class XKeyboard(QtGui.QWidget):
  '''Special virtual keyboard for any language.'''
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.MainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.TextEntry = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    self.Keyboard = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.MainLayout.addWidget(self.TextEntry)
    self.MainLayout.addLayout(self.Keyboard)
    self.setLayout(self.MainLayout)

  def addRow(self, keys):
    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    buttons = [QtGui.QPushButton(unicode(key)) for key in keys]
    for button in buttons:
      key = keys[buttons.index(button)]
      layout.addWidget(button)
      button.clicked.connect(
          lambda key: self.keyClick(key))
      self.keyClick(key)
    self.Keyboard.addLayout(layout)

  def keyClick(self, key):
    self.TextEntry.insertPlainText(key)
```

The problem is that lambda returns `False` instead of key. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `lambda` :

```
lambda key: self.keyClick(key)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
def dummy(key):
    self.keyClick(key)
```

So, basically you are accepting a parameter from `clicked` signal, which [returns](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) `checked` state of the button and it is `False` since you don't have a check-able button, and passing it to the `keyClick` method. `keyClick` method does not receive the `key` parameter in the for loop.

Possible solution would be writing your `lambda` accepting two parameters one with the default value of your intended value:

```
lambda checked, key=key: self.keyClick(key)
```

Why you need to do `key=key` is a whole different subject. [This particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938493/843822) (along with the other answers) from a related subject might shed some light on it.

Comment: Yeah, man, that works! Only one question: if I generate signal that doesn't return any state (like __triggered()__), do I still need __lambda checked, key=key__ or I can write __lambda key=key__?

Comment: @ghostmansd: You should (not "can") write `lambda key=key`, otherwise you'll get and exception stating insufficient parameters. I put `checked` there because you need to discard the parameter passed from `clicked`.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this is to use a [QButtonGroup](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html), which is designed for precisely this situation.

Here's one way to re-write your example to use it:

```
class XKeyboard(QtGui.QWidget):
  '''Special virtual keyboard for any language.'''
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.MainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.TextEntry = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    self.Keyboard = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.MainLayout.addWidget(self.TextEntry)
    self.MainLayout.addLayout(self.Keyboard)
    self.setLayout(self.MainLayout)
    self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
    self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.keyClick)

  def addRow(self, keys):
    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    for key in keys:
        key = unicode(key)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton(key)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(button, ord(key))
        layout.addWidget(button)
    self.Keyboard.addLayout(layout)

  def keyClick(self, key):
    self.TextEntry.insertPlainText(unichr(key))
```