# Lambda function and variable scope

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt, pyqt4, scope

Currently, my code is like this:

```
for control in self.controls():
  self.connect(control, SIGNAL('clicked()'), lambda: self.button(control.objectName()))
```

When I run my code, my `lambda` function takes `control` to be the *last* element in my list of elements, which is not what I expect to happen.

Oddly enough, when I manually run the `lambda` every loop, it works fine for each loop, but it still has the same problem as before in the end:

```
for control in self.controls():
  func = lambda: self.button(control.objectName())
  func() # Prints the correct output

  self.connect(control, SIGNAL('clicked()'), func) # When triggered, still breaks
```

My `self.button()` function is trivially defined:

```
def button(self, name):
    print name
```

I checked for the uniqueness of `control` and `func` every loop by printing the output of `id(control)` and `id(func)` and they all returned unique numbers. Aside from that, `control.objectName()` is the correct object name.

I have a feeling that this is a variable scope problem, as I usually don't use `lambda`s too often in my code. Does anybody see any blatant mistakes?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters)

Comment: And as a side note: Consider using [new style signals/slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html).

Comment: @Avaris: I switched *right* after I posted my question. Thanks for the link, though, I didn't know there was official documentation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SPLAT.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/)

```
for control in self.controls():
  self.connect(control, SIGNAL('clicked()'), lambda control=control:
    self.button(control.objectName()))
```