# Python: Assign a function to a dynamically created radio button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and have a task to take input from a listbox and create radiobuttons for each entry. In my code I am able to create the radio buttons but they don't function when I click on them i.e. in this case they don't print "hello" and the number i. Here's the code:

```
def generateGraph():
    w = Toplevel(bg = "grey")
    w.resizable(0,0)
    frameData = Frame(w, bg="grey", padx=10, pady=10)
    frameData.grid(row = 0, column=0, pady = 1, padx = 1, sticky = N+E+S+W)
    InputLabel = Label(frameData, text="Inputs:", bg="grey")
    InputLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, sticky=N+E+S+W)
    OutputLabel = Label(frameData, text="Outputs:", bg="grey")
    OutputLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, sticky=N+E+S+W)

    i=0
    c=[]
    inputVar = IntVar()
    while(InputBox.get(i)):
        c.append(Radiobutton(frameData, text=InputBox.get(i), variable=inputVar, value = i, background="grey", command= hello(i)))
        c[i].grid(row = i+2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        i=i+1
    if makemodal:
        w.focus_set()
        w.grab_set()
        w.wait_window()
def hello(i):
    print("hello %d" %i)
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't your first post - remember to indent your post properly and ensure everything that should be in a codeblock is

Comment: Done. Thank you. Do you have any idea as to how we do it?

Comment: This isn't your problem (see my answer for that), but: Why are you attaching a `command` to a `Radiobutton`? That's not typical UI behavior. Normally radio buttons are there to select a value, which will be used by some other action later.

Comment: As a side note: It's generally bad style to have 131-character-long lines, but that's especially true when you're posting on SO, which will force anyone to use a horizontal scrollbar just to see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `hello(i)` at the time of construction of the `Radiobutton`, not storing something to be called later:

```
    c.append(Radiobutton(frameData, text=InputBox.get(i), variable=inputVar, value = i, background="grey", command= hello(i)))
```

Since `hello` returns `None`, you're effectively storing `command=None`.

You need to store a callable here, like `hello` itself, (or a `lambda` or `partial`, or whatever), not the result of calling it.

For example:

```
    c.append(Radiobutton(frameData, text=InputBox.get(i), 
                         variable=inputVar, value = i, background="grey",
                         command=functools.partial(hello, i)))
```

Since you asked in the comments: Note that I used `partial` rather than `lambda`, because I want to bind in the value of `i`, not close over the variable `i`. Otherwise, you'd end up with, e.g., 5 radio buttons all bound to the same variable `i` with the value `4`. There are other ways around this—use an explicit factory, do `lambda x=i: hello(x)` instead of `lambda: hello(i)`, etc. To me, `partial` seems like the clearest and most explicit, but your mileage may vary. Anyway, there are dozens of questions on SO about this, but the answer to [Scope of python lambda functions and their parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters) seems particularly clear.

Comment: Thank you for that. But now the problem is that how do I know which radio button is clicked? i.e. now it's printing the last updated value of i whenever any button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, because you're creating a lambda for each `Radiobutton` that all close over the same `i` variable. There are dozens of SO questions about that, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters), which will show you how to do the right thing.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at it. :)

Comment: @Vishesh: I edited the answer with the way I personally would do it. If that makes sense to you, great. But most people who don't think "partial evaluation is what I want" aren't going to understand why it's the right answer, so it's worth learning why this happens, and how the different solutions all work.