# IronPython Multiprocessing Module

Tags: multithreading, ironpython

I have some dlls written in Dotnet which I am using to access thousands of binary files. The data is compartmentalized by directories, so as a performance enhancement I thought of using multiple processes or threads to churn through the files.

I have a function, currently part of the main class (requiring self as an argument), this could easily be refactored to a private method.

My first inclination is to use the Multiprocess module, but that doesn't seem to be available for IronPython.

My next thought was to use Task

```
def __createThreads(self):
    tasks = Array.CreateInstance(Task, 5)
    for idx in range(0, 5):
        tasks.append(Task.Factory.StartNew(self.__doWork, args=(idx,)))

    Task.WaitAll(tasks)

def __doWork(self, idx):

    for index in range (0, idx):
        print "Thread: %d | Index: %d" % (idx, index)
```

Or to use Thread

```
def __createThreads(self):
    threads = list()
    for idx in range(0, 5):
        t = Thread(ThreadStart(self.__doWork))
        t.Start()
        threads.append(t)

    while len(threads) > 0:
        time.sleep(.05)
        for t in threads:
            if(not t.IsAlive):
                threads.remove(t)
```

What I cannot find is a IronPython example of how to pass arguements

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that your two examples are not exactly equivalent. The task version will only create/use actual concurrent threads when the run-time thinks it is a good idea (unless you specify [TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx)). You have to decide what works for your use-case.

The easiest way to pass the **idx** argument to the **__doWork** function would be using a lambda to capture the value and invocation. (please be aware of scoping issues as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/938429/468244) which also hints at alternative solutions for introducing an intermediate scope)

```
tasks.append(Task.Factory.StartNew(lambda idx = idx: self.__doWork(idx)))
```

As a side-note: You will have to convert your task list to an array in order for Task.WaitAll to be happy.

Comment: Thanks, and that leads to the obvious next question which is how to specify the task as long running. The documentation doesn't include IronPython.

Comment: There is really nothing IronPython specific in terms of documentation. Except for a few corner cases you can just use all .net APIs as expected. [StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321263.aspx) just takes the creation options as the second argument which would look like `tasks.append(Task.Factory.StartNew(lambda idx = idx: self.__doWork(idx), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning))` for sour sample.