# Define a list of lambdas in Python that is eagerly evaluated

Tags: python, lambda, closures, lazy-evaluation

I'd like to programmatically create a list of functions, each of which returns a dictionary with a specific key, and always the same value. That is:

```
l1 = [lambda _: {0: 42}, lambda _: {2: 42}, lambda _: {3: 42}]
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result programmatically.
To try and avoid the usual problem with lazy evaluation, I thought I'd only need to create a generator for generating the functions on the fly:

```
gen = (lambda _: {f: 42} for f in range(3))
```

And then use a simple list comprehension to get the list:

```
l2 = [f for f in gen]
```

That's not sufficient. In fact, if you compare `func_clousures` with one another, they're all the same:

```
x[0].func_closure == x[1].func_closure == x[2].func_closure  # this is True
```

What's the best way to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but how is `create a list of functions, each of which returns a dictionary with a specific key, and always the same value` any different to a list of dicts?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: the values are to be evaluated later.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan The main difference is I'm looking for a list of functions (callable objects, really) whereas a list of dicts is not callable. Put it another way, I need to be able to call `l2[0]('something')`.

Comment: Well known Python scoping gotcha. Short answer : `gen = (lambda _, f=f: {f: 42} for f in range(3))`, long answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you're the one who nailed it (2 args needed). If you turn your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the one.

Comment: Side note: `[f for f in gen]` is written more directly as `list(gen)`.

Comment: @Jir: I voted to close this question as duplicate (cf the link) so I don't see the point in posting it as a full answer - the question I linked to already explain the whole thing ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: yup, I saw that later :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the last value of `f` to all the lambdas:

```
gen = (lambda _,f=f: {f: 42} for f in range(3))
```

As @Jon Clements so kindly pointed out the term is lazy binding, which is described in [Common_Gotchas_In_Python](http://sopython.com/wiki/Common_Gotchas_In_Python)

Comment: You can nick & elaborate on the sentence from "Lazy Binding" on [sopython](http://sopython.com/wiki/Common_Gotchas_In_Python/) if you want... :p

Comment: @JonClements, nicked ;)

Answer (score 0):

First it depends on which python version you are using. Pyhton3 creates lazy generators for most of iterators. So you could do something like:

```
l2 = list([lambda: {f: 42} for f in range(3)])
```

or if you your lambda needs an input parameter

```
l2 = list([lambda f: {f: 42} for f in range(3)])
```