# Python3's filter with lambda function and generator

Tags: python, filter, lambda, generator, python-itertools

Please, consider this Python 3 code to generate prime numbers using an unbounded sieve of eratosthenes:

```
import itertools
def primes():
    numbers = itertools.count(2)
    while True:
        prime = next(numbers)
        yield prime
        numbers = filter(prime.__rmod__,numbers)

prime_gen = primes()
next(prime_gen)
# Prints 2
next(prime_gen)
# Prints 3
next(prime_gen)
# Prints 5
next(prime_gen)
# Prints 7
```

So far so good. Now, let's replace the `prime.__rmod__` function with a lambda that does the same thing:

```
import itertools
def primes():
    numbers = itertools.count(2)
    while True:
        prime = next(numbers)
        yield prime
        numbers = filter(lambda n: n % prime,numbers)

prime_gen = primes()
next(prime_gen)
# Prints 2
next(prime_gen)
# Prints 3
next(prime_gen)
# Prints 4
next(prime_gen)
# Prints 5
```

**Why the lambda function is not working with the filter?** There is something going on with the scope of the lambda function?

Comment: yes, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters) for more info on why this is the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do lambda function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)

Answer (score 0):

As R Nar comments this is due to the scope of the lambda function. Because `prime` is global to the lambda function the same value for `prime` is used in every lambda when `filter` tries to do its job. The solution is creating a closure for each lambda in order to make them remember the value of `prime` when they are created:

```
filter(lambda n, prime=prime: n % prime,numbers)
```