# Currying in Python lambdas

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, scope, currying

I'm trying to write a naive curried function in Python 2.7, but it seems like the inner lambda doesn't have an access to the parent lambda scope.

For simplicity, let's take this function:

```
add = lambda a: lambda b: a + b
```

The inner lambda's scope can't access the outer one (Python can't recognize `a`).

Is there a convenient way to make the outer scope accessible?

Comment: It works: `>>> add = lambda x: lambda b: b + x ;
>>> add(5)(2) ;
7`

Comment: Voted to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

This example seems to work for me in python 2.7.11

```
add = lambda a: lambda b: a + b
f = add(1)
print f(2)
3
print f(10)
11
```

More complicated examples might fall down though. A lambda function stores references to the variables in the enclosing scope, rather than their values. This might help with a more complicated problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/938493/8131703

Comment: If it does, it should be a comment, not an answer.