# How does the adders function work when we add number to the first element?

Tags: python, lambda

```
adders = []
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    add_i = lambda x: x + i
    adders.append(add_i)

adders

[<function __main__.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>>]
```

If we input `add1 = adders[0]`, then `add1` will be `x+1`. But `add1 (5)` outputs `8` instead of `6`. Why?

Comment: Could you provide the code that you use to obtain `8` in this case?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed an argument. It should be `add1 = adders[0]`, then `add1(5)` output `8`.

Comment: This is a problem with `lambda` scopes, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters). You can use `lambda x, i=i: x + i` to get the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess the 3 `lambda` functions in my code are the same thing, which is the last one `lambda x: x + 3`.

Comment: They are three distinct function objects doing the same thing. This is different from `adders` containing 3 references to the same function.