# Keras custom layer issue for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to dynamically create layers in Keras (Lambda Layers) but for some reason when I use for loop I get the same error in the list, compared to manually appending elements into the list.

Where is my bug?

```
other_channels_out = []
out_channel = []

for i in range(out_number_model_0):
    layer = Lambda(lambda xx: K.expand_dims(xx))(Lambda(lambda y: y[:, i])(model_0.output))
    if i != channel:
        other_channels_out.append(layer)
    else:
        out_channel.append(layer)
```

Vs

```
other_channels_out.append(Lambda(lambda xx: K.expand_dims(xx))(Lambda(lambda y: y[:, 0])(model_0.output)))
other_channels_out.append(Lambda(lambda xx: K.expand_dims(xx))(Lambda(lambda y: y[:, 1])(model_0.output)))
out_channel.append(Lambda(lambda xx: K.expand_dims(xx))(Lambda(lambda y: y[:, 2])(model_0.output)))
```

The list consist of : [a,a,a,a] vs [a,b,c,d]

Comment: As an aside, `lambda xx: K.expand_dims(xx)` is more neatly written as `K.expand_dims` (no parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

Making a function to generate the layer seems to solve it.
But I would like some explanation?

```
    other_channels_out = []
out_channel = []

def createLambda(i,input):
    _layer = Lambda(lambda xx: K.expand_dims(xx))(Lambda(lambda y: y[:, i])(input))
    return _layer

for i in range(out_number_model_0):
    if i != channel:
        other_channels_out.append(createLambda(i, model_0.output))
    else:
        out_channel.append(createLambda(i, model_0.output))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but the issue is that the scope of `i` is outside the `lambda` function, so the value of `i` changes after the `lambda` is created. By moving the `Lambda` (and hence `lambda`) creation to another function, you've redefined the scope of `i`.

Related: [Scope of lambda functions and their parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters)